# regex - how to find the match that before and nearest to the otehr

Tags: regex

I have a log file to analyze, look like this

12:14 
(something)
13:15 
(something)
13:16 
(something)
Pwr=123 
(something)
13:17 
(something)
13:18 
(something)
Pwr=456 
(something)

I would like to find the all the numbers following "Pwr=" and pair with the time stamps that before it? So at the end of the day I will have pairs:
   13:16 123
   13:18 456

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming not each entry is on a separate line, this extracts the timestamp into capture group 1 and the Pwr value in capture group 2, unless *(something)* contains something other than characters, digits or underscores

```
(\d{2}:\d{2})\s\(\w+?\)\sPwr=(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each entry is a line,

`^(\d+:\d+).*Pwr=(\d+).*`

This will put a HH:MM timestamp in capture group 1, and the Pwr value in capture group 2.

Comment: This will capture the whole string, if not every entry is on a line

Comment: @blueygh2 I mentioned that proviso. Because what "something" is isn't quite clear (what happens if something can be 00:00?), this is actually tricky to do when log entries aren't delimited.

Comment: It's tricky to devise a correct regex, if it's not clear what *something* can be